# How to check whether a user has permission WITH GRANT OPTION?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL Server 2012 I can grant a user some permission with a special option "WITH GRANT OPTION":

```
USE MyDatabase
GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO MyUser WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Now if I login to the server with this user and check its permission:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('MyDatabase', 'DATABASE', 'ALTER ANY USER')
```

It gives my "1" as expected (the user really has the "ALTER ANY USER" permission). But how do I check that the user has this permission with the option "WITH GRANT OPTION"?
I'd expect probably something like this:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('MyDatabase', 'DATABASE', 'ALTER ANY USER WITH GRANT OPTION')
```

But of course it does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to query [`sys.database_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx):

```
select state from sys.database_permissions
where class_desc='DATABASE' and
      permission_name='ALTER ANY USER' and
      grantee_principal_id = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID()
```

And state will be `G` for a plain grant and `W` for `WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: Thanks it works with described case. I marked it as an answer. But unfortunately it does not work in more general case - whether a user such as sysadmin has permission to grant permissions to other users. I mean  for example if I have sysadmin role - I can grant any permission to another user, but if I run this script for sysadmin - result will be empty (it works only if you granted permission with "GRANT OPTION" explicitly). Basically what I really need - it's a way to know whether a user has a permission to grant this permission to another user. Probably I should open another question on SO.